# java.io.IOExceptin: Stream closed when parsing JSON from Jackson

Tags: jackson, java-io

I am trying to parse a JSON object which looks like this after dumping via perl

```
{
  "customerID":"random",
  "sessionID":"192-3105199-8486749"
}
```

When I try to deserialize I get the following exception -

```
[tomcat:launch] java.io.IOException: Stream closed
[tomcat:launch] at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.read (InputBuffer.java:413
[tomcat:launch] at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteReader.read (CoyoteReader.java:108
[tomcat:launch] at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser.loadMore (ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:127)
[tomcat:launch] at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser._skipWSOrEnd (ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:1659)
[tomcat:launch] at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser.nextToken (ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:561)
[tomcat:launch] at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._initForReading (ObjectMapper.java:2834)
[tomcat:launch] at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose (ObjectMapper.java:2781)
[tomcat:launch] at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue (ObjectMapper.java:1965)
```

I am fairly new to JSON and have no clue whatsoever what is going wrong.

Comment: Could you show your source code?

Comment: Closing the question. I was parsing the parameters incorrectly using the URL encoding. I changed that configuration to use JSON format instead and everything worked. Thanks anyway!